# Eclipse: Project name conflict when importing branch project

Tags: eclipse, branch

We can't import projects which have same name like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7832761/import-different-versions-of-a-project-into-eclipse). It annoys me whenever I try to import a *branch project* into Eclipse while I also work with a *trunk project*. I have to change the name of *trunk project* to import the *branch project*. Is there any better idea to deal with this situation?

Comment: there's a request: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=40493

Comment: @PaulWebster As of today, the bug is 11 years old...

Comment: That's why it's marked "helpwanted"

Answer (score 2):

One simple way would be to import your second project in a separate workspace and switch between the two workspaces.

This isn't ideal if you need to work on *both* at the same time, but you don't need to rename your project that way.

Answer (score 1):

You can also choose a different name for the project to be imported.

How do you import? For example the Subversion plugin has "Find/Checkout as..." which lets you specify a different name.

The ultimate fallback that should always work is to [update the .project file to be imported](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7832929/14955).

And then there is the option of having multiple workspaces.