# How to import android project properly into Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, import

I tried many answers there but non solved the problem.

I have an android project (lets name it `t`) that I created using the eclipse into its workspace folder.

I did the following:

- I copied `t` into another place as a backup.
- Then, I deleted it from eclipse -> **R-click** on `t` then **delete**.
- When I checked the workspace, it was removed as expected.
  **Then.**
- I copied the backup into the workspace.
- I tried to open it on eclipse, but with no success.

  - File -> Import -> Android -> Existing Android Code Into WorkSpace -> Next -> Browse (to the project folder in the workspace itself) -> Finish (Last step).
- After the last step, the dialog box disappeared (as expected) without a warning message. But `t` was not added (became visible) into the Package Explorer of Eclipse!!.
- I checked the workspace folder, the project `t` I wanted to open was still there

How to fix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try leaving the project folder outside of the workspace during the import.

When you re-import the project, check the "copy project files into workspace" box.

In my experience, manually copying projects into (or out of) the workspace can be troublesome.

Comment: Thank you. I tried your solution it was OK. There is one extra step to add to your answer (as improvement). I first deleted my project from `workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.projects`. If not deleted from there, attempting to import it was unsuccessful.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should check the error log...probably Eclipse won't let you import it, with a message "Some projects cannot be imported because they already exist in the workspace". If this is the case, using/creating another workspace should fix the problem. If you don't want to change workspace, you may want to check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7832761/import-different-versions-of-a-project-into-eclipse) post.

Answer (score 0):

New ->Other ->Android Project from Existing Code ->(Browse to Root Directory )->select Projects to Imports -> check Copy projects into working sets ->finish