# android how to open slider images when onclick image and swipe with fingers

Tags: android, android-animation

My question is i am working on application,which have images slider,and the images comes from the server,now my question is when i click on my images it's look like this,see the following example images,and also with swipe functionality that i can see my images with finger swipe,any idea and help will be highly appreciated.

before image click:

[image]

after when click on image:

[image]

Comment: have you tried anything??

Comment: Thanks for ur reply.yes i have tried many things but it's not worked..i need to the exact my problem solving instructions or any help or idea.

Comment: for that you need to use viewpager or viewflipper..

Answer (score 2):

Try to use this library it would be very helpful. It will save a lot of time.But for both functionality you have to use viewpager also.

https://github.com/Dreddik/AndroidTouchGallery

Comment: i have import the project and library..but the project give me error,i have right click on project>properties>java build path>Libraries,in there android dependies showing error when i taped,it's showing Library.jar is missing?any idea.

Comment: Have you added suport-v4 jar ?

Comment: Means there is no problem with library, problem with example?

Comment: i have just build the library and problem is solved.thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Below code may help you.

First create adapter class.

```
public class FullScreenImageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {  
private Activity _activity;
private ArrayList<String> _imagePaths;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
// constructor
public FullScreenImageAdapter(Activity activity,
        ArrayList<String> imagePaths) {
    this._activity = activity;
    this._imagePaths = imagePaths;
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return this._imagePaths.size();
}
@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view == ((RelativeLayout) object);
}
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    TouchImageView imgDisplay;
    Button btnClose;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) _activity
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View viewLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_fullscreen_image, container,
            false);
    imgDisplay = (TouchImageView) viewLayout.findViewById(R.id.imgDisplay);
    btnClose = (Button) viewLayout.findViewById(R.id.btnClose);

    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(_imagePaths.get(position), options);
    imgDisplay.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    // close button click event
    btnClose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {            
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            _activity.finish();
        }
    }); 
    ((ViewPager) container).addView(viewLayout);
    return viewLayout;
}
@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    ((ViewPager) container).removeView((RelativeLayout) object);
}
}
```

This is the xml file used in this class:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<info.androidhive.imageslider.helper.TouchImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgDisplay"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnClose"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:paddingTop="2dp"
    android:paddingBottom="2dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_background"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:text="Close" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the activity:

```
import com.example.crystalgallery.R;
import info.androidhive.imageslider.adapter.FullScreenImageAdapter;
import info.androidhive.imageslider.helper.Utils;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ActivityManager;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

public class FullScreenViewActivity extends Activity{
private FullScreenImageAdapter adapter;
private ViewPager viewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen_view);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    adapter = new FullScreenImageAdapter(FullScreenViewActivity.this,
            FilePaths);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    // displaying selected image first
    viewPager.setCurrentItem("You can set the position of selected item here");
}
```

xml file of activity class:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:background="#000000">

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

TouchImageView.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.PointF;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.ScaleGestureDetector;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class TouchImageView extends ImageView {

Matrix matrix;

// We can be in one of these 3 states
static final int NONE = 0;
static final int DRAG = 1;
static final int ZOOM = 2;
int mode = NONE;

// Remember some things for zooming
PointF last = new PointF();
PointF start = new PointF();
float minScale = 1f;
float maxScale = 3f;
float[] m;

int viewWidth, viewHeight;
static final int CLICK = 3;
float saveScale = 1f;
protected float origWidth, origHeight;
int oldMeasuredWidth, oldMeasuredHeight;

ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;

Context context;

public TouchImageView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    sharedConstructing(context);
}

public TouchImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    sharedConstructing(context);
}

private void sharedConstructing(Context context) {
    super.setClickable(true);
    this.context = context;
    mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());
    matrix = new Matrix();
    m = new float[9];
    setImageMatrix(matrix);
    setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);

    setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
            PointF curr = new PointF(event.getX(), event.getY());

            switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                last.set(curr);
                start.set(last);
                mode = DRAG;
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                if (mode == DRAG) {
                    float deltaX = curr.x - last.x;
                    float deltaY = curr.y - last.y;
                    float fixTransX = getFixDragTrans(deltaX, viewWidth,
                            origWidth * saveScale);
                    float fixTransY = getFixDragTrans(deltaY, viewHeight,
                            origHeight * saveScale);
                    matrix.postTranslate(fixTransX, fixTransY);
                    fixTrans();
                    last.set(curr.x, curr.y);
                }
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                mode = NONE;
                int xDiff = (int) Math.abs(curr.x - start.x);
                int yDiff = (int) Math.abs(curr.y - start.y);
                if (xDiff < CLICK && yDiff < CLICK)
                    performClick();
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                mode = NONE;
                break;
            }

            setImageMatrix(matrix);
            invalidate();
            return true; // indicate event was handled
        }

    });
}

public void setMaxZoom(float x) {
    maxScale = x;
}

private class ScaleListener extends
        ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
        mode = ZOOM;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
        float mScaleFactor = detector.getScaleFactor();
        float origScale = saveScale;
        saveScale *= mScaleFactor;
        if (saveScale > maxScale) {
            saveScale = maxScale;
            mScaleFactor = maxScale / origScale;
        } else if (saveScale < minScale) {
            saveScale = minScale;
            mScaleFactor = minScale / origScale;
        }

        if (origWidth * saveScale <= viewWidth
                || origHeight * saveScale <= viewHeight)
            matrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, viewWidth / 2,
                    viewHeight / 2);
        else
            matrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor,
                    detector.getFocusX(), detector.getFocusY());

        fixTrans();
        return true;
    }
}

void fixTrans() {
    matrix.getValues(m);
    float transX = m[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
    float transY = m[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];

    float fixTransX = getFixTrans(transX, viewWidth, origWidth * saveScale);
    float fixTransY = getFixTrans(transY, viewHeight, origHeight
            * saveScale);

    if (fixTransX != 0 || fixTransY != 0)
        matrix.postTranslate(fixTransX, fixTransY);
}

float getFixTrans(float trans, float viewSize, float contentSize) {
    float minTrans, maxTrans;

    if (contentSize <= viewSize) {
        minTrans = 0;
        maxTrans = viewSize - contentSize;
    } else {
        minTrans = viewSize - contentSize;
        maxTrans = 0;
    }

    if (trans < minTrans)
        return -trans + minTrans;
    if (trans > maxTrans)
        return -trans + maxTrans;
    return 0;
}

float getFixDragTrans(float delta, float viewSize, float contentSize) {
    if (contentSize <= viewSize) {
        return 0;
    }
    return delta;
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    viewWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    viewHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

    //
    // Rescales image on rotation
    //
    if (oldMeasuredHeight == viewWidth && oldMeasuredHeight == viewHeight
            || viewWidth == 0 || viewHeight == 0)
        return;
    oldMeasuredHeight = viewHeight;
    oldMeasuredWidth = viewWidth;

    if (saveScale == 1) {
        // Fit to screen.
        float scale;

        Drawable drawable = getDrawable();
        if (drawable == null || drawable.getIntrinsicWidth() == 0
                || drawable.getIntrinsicHeight() == 0)
            return;
        int bmWidth = drawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
        int bmHeight = drawable.getIntrinsicHeight();

        Log.d("bmSize", "bmWidth: " + bmWidth + " bmHeight : " + bmHeight);

        float scaleX = (float) viewWidth / (float) bmWidth;
        float scaleY = (float) viewHeight / (float) bmHeight;
        scale = Math.min(scaleX, scaleY);
        matrix.setScale(scale, scale);

        // Center the image
        float redundantYSpace = (float) viewHeight
                - (scale * (float) bmHeight);
        float redundantXSpace = (float) viewWidth
                - (scale * (float) bmWidth);
        redundantYSpace /= (float) 2;
        redundantXSpace /= (float) 2;

        matrix.postTranslate(redundantXSpace, redundantYSpace);

        origWidth = viewWidth - 2 * redundantXSpace;
        origHeight = viewHeight - 2 * redundantYSpace;
        setImageMatrix(matrix);
    }
    fixTrans();
}
}
```

Note: Try to change the package name used in this code and xml with yours.

You can open image in fullscreen and can swipe now. And in this code there is a button to close that full screen image. If u don't need that,then avoid that button creation and its click.

Comment: Thanks Alot for ur ans..ok i will check,now currentely i have start another module when complete the current module then i get back to image slider with finger swipe module and i will let u know.

Comment: @FarhanShah: Ok..Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

Use View Pager like that

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

also visit that [View Pager](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-fullscreen-image-slider-with-swipe-and-pinch-zoom-gestures/)

Comment: Thanks for ur reply..ok i visit ur link,i am checking and get back to you that what i have done..

Comment: i have import the sample code it's error like this "NAT directory path is not valid! Please set the image directory name AppConstant.java class"..

Comment: check that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17973431/how-to-import-android-project-properly-into-eclipse